# Handling response from database and passing it to new activity

Tags: java, android, json

I am currently building a login system for a simple game application. What I am trying to achieve is the following: When a user logs in I want to display the top 5 highscores in the activity the user comes to after logging in.

The response I am getting from the database is a JSON encoded string looking like this:

```
{"success":true,"toplist":
   [{"username":"Tom","score":"4200"},
   {"username":"John","score":"2303"},
   {"username":"Benjamin","score":"700"},
   {"username":"Michael","score":"648"},
   {"username":"Daniel","score":"500"}]
}
```

From here I would like to "handle" and pass the top 5 information to the userAreaActivity and then show the top 5 in a table.

Here is what I have so far in order to handle the response:

```
bSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success){

                            Intent userAreaIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);

                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(userAreaIntent);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login failed!")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
```

If it is of any use this is what my UserAreaActivity.Java looks like:

```
public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

       final TableLayout tlHighscores = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlHighscores);

       Intent intent = getIntent();      

   }
}
```

Would be thrilled if someone would give me some guidance as to how I would do this in the most convenient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
Intent userAreaIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
userAreaIntent.putString("data", jsonResponse.toString());
LoginActivity.this.startActivity(userAreaIntent);
```

And in UserAreaActivity

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("data"));
```

Once you get the jsonObj you can parse it and use it anyway you want.

Comment: @christian Did you try my answer, if you found it useful can you please consider upvoting it !!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Posted the question when i was about to go to bed, but it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Intent object is for - to provide an intent along with associated information. You can simply do:

Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserAreaActivity.class);
intent.putString("key", "value");
startActivity(intent);

Now, you can do intent.getStringExtra("key") in your receiving Acitivity to extract the values. You can pass your entire JSON string and retrieve information this way.